# How to scrape website with table build in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, powershell, invoke-webrequest

I'd like to scrape a websites table with Powershell but I found out this website is building the table with a javascript.
This is the website: https://www.gunzodus.net/auction
And I'd like to scrape the table with the header "Characters for Sale", but as you can see in the source this table is generated with javascript so the standard Powershell Invoke-Webrequest $url & select the table # won't work.
Does anyone know how to extract the javascript from the sourcecode? I see there is a javascript that starts with "var sellCharactersData". If I could only extract this line I could parse this line further in the script.

Comment: the only way i know of is to use something like Selenium to run the page and THEN grab the info.

Comment: Use a headless browser and automated tools. Like MS's Playwright, or Google's Puppeteer.

Comment: You can use, somethink like phantomjs to execute the javascript, then take what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is probably a better way but for now I solved it by using this:

```
$web = Invoke-WebRequest "https://www.gunzodus.net/auction"
$web.tostring() -split "[`r`n]" | select-string "sellCharactersData"
```